# How to get object with min/max parameter in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with similar objects:

```
{
   _id: "1"
   itemList: [
      { itemId: "23", price: 234 },
      { itemId: "24", price: 444 },
      { itemId: "25", price: 268 },
   ]
}
```

I need to addItems with min price (it is easy) and id of object with min price - no idea how to do it.
In result I need to have something like this:

```
{
   _id: "1"
   itemList: [
      { itemId: "23", price: 234 },
      { itemId: "24", price: 444 },
      { itemId: "25", price: 268 },
   ]
   minPrice: 234,
   minPriceItemId: "23"
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in particular you are struggling with, or is it just a statement that you need something but have no ideas?

Comment: I don't know how to get id of object with min price... I am struggling with hours...

Comment: A few thoughts: unwind/sort the array by the desired field, group and pull the first/last entry, or use reduce.  Also if 2 items have the same minimum price, how will you decide which ID to use?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$set: {
minPrice: {$arrayElemAt: ["$itemList", {$indexOfArray: ["$itemList.price", {$min: "$itemList.price"}]}]
}}}
])
```

And result will become:

```
{
        "_id" : "1",
        "itemList" : [
                {
                        "itemId" : "23",
                        "price" : 234
                },
                {
                        "itemId" : "24",
                        "price" : 444
                },
                {
                        "itemId" : "25",
                        "price" : 268
                }
        ],
        "minPrice" : {
                "itemId" : "23",
                "price" : 234
        }
}
```